# Qt terrain example doesn't work

Tags: qt, opengl

i get a Qt example about terrain tessellation at http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-5/
, but i have a problem in the output reads:
Total number of patches = 25600 
Error - RtlWerpReportException failed with status code :-1073741823. Will try to launch the process directly.
My computer is AMD A6 series and Qt 5.1.0.What's wrong?

Comment: Please add your environement: OS, IDE + Version and whether you got special settings (e.g. struct member alignment). How are you trying to compile it?

Comment: Could you add your code as well? kinda hard guessing what the error might be caused by, if we don't see any code!